# How to reduce the number of threads a nodejs server is using?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, winston

I am running a fairly simple server on a machine that is quite limited in resources. The bottleneck I'm hitting is that my account is limited to 40 processes/threads running at once. When I run my nodejs app and check htop I see that my node server runs 1 main thread and 10 child threads. 5 additional processes are taken up by using `forever` to execute the node script (I wanted to use pm2 but it used too many processes).

The thing is that I want to be able to have simultaneously 2 instances of my server running at one time (a master production branch and a dev branch that will be used for further development) so this puts me at 32/40 processes.

Add in the fact that I use tmux with a couple of windows to monitor and manage my server and I am basically hitting the limit. If I hit the limit and log out, I cannot ssh back in and have to contact support to kill some of my processes. That is not very good for a production environment.

So I'd like to ask, is there a way to limit the number of threads my nodejs server is using? I suspect that nodejs itself uses just a single thread so I've been looking through my dependencies but haven't any mentions of multiple threads running.

```
nodejs version: v12.9.0
dependencies:
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "commander": "^4.1.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "csv-parse": "^4.8.5",
        "csv-writer": "^1.6.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "request": "^2.88.0",
        "winston": "^3.2.1",
        "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.4.2"
```

The most plausible solution right now seems to be to stop using `forever` and simply write my own simple bash or python script with an endless while loop and simple conditions. But I'd prefer using existing tested software that has some further monitoring capabilities.

Comment: Well, the file I/O sub-system uses a thread pool for disk I/O (internal to LIBUV).  By default, I think it uses 4 threads.  You could reduce it.  See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_uv_threadpool_size_size) and [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html) for more info.  You should be able to find something that would serve the purpose of forever without using 5 threads.

Comment: Alright, this actually helps, I was able to reduce it from 4 threads to 1, it saved 3 threads. This might be okay as most FS usage comes from logs which can be slow. There is also the `dns.lookup()` that might be hurting, but all outgoing requests target a single domain. Will that help or will it use `dns.lookup()` nontheless? Regarding the running loop, I am not so sure, the only alternative to forever and pm2 I see is using systemd, which I cannot access as I don't have root. So in the end bash script with a loop will probably be fine as I have quite complete logging already in the app.

Comment: At this point I'm wondering what those other 6 child threads are doing...

Comment: As fat as I know, networking in node.js doesn't use threads so I don't think `dns.lookup()` is causing any issues.

Comment: OS-level threads in node.js are created with `uv_thread_create()`.  So, if you search for that in the nodejs code repository, you get this https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?p=1&q=uv_thread_create.  While, ignoring all the source files that are involved in unit testing, you can see where threads are created inside of node.js by wandering through those search results.  I did not discover anything else that looked like it could be reduced.  IMO, your biggest opportunity is by replacing forever.

Comment: In looking through those search results, I found a system thread related to the following: A watchdog thread that regularly makes some checks, a thread related to the Inspector (and debugging), the thread pool, something related to certain kinds of streams on certain types of unix platforms (perhaps stdio or stdout use a thread on some platforms?), the implementation of nodejs worker threads, and something related to "tracing" (which I think is more debugging tools).

Comment: So, the only idea that looking through the source generated was to try to close the stdio and stdout streams and see if that made any difference.

Comment: Thanks, from what I looked up, closing the actual streams might prove problematic if the application cannot handle closed files. Could you elaborate on how you think it should be done? Apart from that if I just stop using forever and reduce the LIBUV worker pool to 1, I am left with 1 main + 7 child threads + 1 runner process = 9 per server instance, which is actually acceptable, that leaves me enough leeway for managing the server without being too worried or needing to be too cautious.

Comment: Yeah, closing stdin/stdout/stderr obviously depends upon whether you're app is trying to use them.  My suggestion was assuming it was not trying to use them.  stdout is where `console.log()` goes by default so that might be problematic.  You could experiment with closing `stdin` (assuming you aren't using it) and see if affects the thread count on your platform.  I think you would just do `process.stdin.destroy()` and see if the thread count was any lower.

Comment: Okay, yeah that makes sense and in that case it might be possible to close both stdin and stdout. I'm using winston for logging and I can simply disable the console trasport. Node shouldn't try to output anything on its own, correct?

Comment: First see if it even saves you a thread by destroying `stdin` which is easier to know you're not using.  Then, you can experiment with whether you can close more of them or not.  From the nodejs code, I couldn't really tell what circumstances and on what platforms a stream would use a thread so this is just an experiment.

Comment: alright, I tried both `process.stdin.destroy()` and `process.stdout.destroy()`, neither of them crashed the app but unfortunately nor did they save any threads. S\till at 7 children.

Comment: OK, not something that helps you on your platform.  Just an experiment.